# High precision date/time stamp in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have bulk records that are getting imported into a SQL Server 2005 table.  I need to be able to maintain the same order that they were imported.  I was using a DateTime field and populating it to GETDATE(), but that wasn't precise enough.

Any advice out there?

Edit, just to clear up...  I don't care what order they appear in the table.  I need to be able to order them and maintain the order they were inserted.  The problem now is that when I do ORDER BY with my DateTime field, several records fall on the same date because of the lack of precision.

Comment: What does the source data look like?

Comment: Anything relying on order of inserts will break sooner or later. If order is important, there should be a field (like Uriah's suggestion) just for that.

Comment: SQL Server 2005 doesn't have anything more precise than `DateTime` (3.33ms) - if you need more precision, down to 100ns, you need to go to SQL Server 2008 and `DateTime2` datatype

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The precision is not high enough because the import is importing more rows per second than there is precision in a datetime datatype?

What mechanism are you using to import the rows?

I would advise a standard identity column, which is pretty much guaranteed to be increasing (but someone can enable identity insert and insert a row anywhere there is a gap, which can occur during a transaction which rolls back due to a constraint violation or similar).

Note that if you have multiple parallel inserts (different connections or whatever), they will be interleaved, so you couldn't use a simple range to find all things which came from a particular source file, say.

A lot of times using SSIS, we had a batch identifier and a sequence number within the batch assigned to rows during the dataflow (separate from any identity which may have existed on the destination table).

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention how you are importing the records, but adding an auto-incrementing identity column to your table should work fine.

Comment: I was pondering this, but I was under the assumption that replying on auto-incrementing identity columns for ordering was a bad practice.  I do think it would do well in my situation though.

Comment: I am going to leave the question open a bit longer to see what other options might be.

Comment: @Mike, relying on identity columns for ordering is way better than order of insert. I assume you need the order of inserts preserved because you wish to select *without* order by clause. Beware that there is *no guarantee* this will return the results in the order you've inserted them.

Comment: @Mike, perhaps if you explain *why* the order of inserts is important to you but not in the original table, we might suggest alternative approaches.

Comment: It's historical transactional workflow data.  I need to always know which workflow step was the last inserted so I know the current workflow.